# Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following Python code that uses Spark:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def simulate(a, b, c):
  dict = Row(a=a, b=b, c=c)
  df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dict)
  return df

df = simulate("a","b",10)
df.collect()
```

I am creating a `Row` object and I want to save it as a `DataFrame`.

However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>
```

It occurs on this line:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dict)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is pointless to create single element data frame. If you want to make it work despite that use list: `df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([dict])`

Comment: Works with warning : UserWarning: inferring schema from dict is deprecated,please use pyspark.sql.Row instead